# Fill loaded variable with nested environment variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a groovy script inside my pipeline that load some text from an json file. Now I want to combine this loaded text with existing environment variable, but it will not fill the placeholder. What I do:

```
json
{
  "resource": {
    "SERVICE_API_URL":"http://my-service-svc.${KUBERNETES_HOST}:5000"
  }
}

script {
  env.KUBERNETES_HOST = "myjenkins"
  env.JSONSTRING = readFile(file: 'pipeline/pipeline.config')
  def propsen = readJSON text: "${env.JSONSTRING}"

  env.test = propsen.resource.SERVICE_API_URL
  echo "${test}"
}
```

I hoped that this will echo `"http://my-service-svc.myjenkins:5000"`
but it still echo `"http://my-service-svc.${KUBERNETES_HOST}:5000"`

So is there a trick how to do fill this "nested" variable in a dynamic loaded variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `env` to your variable in  `*.json` file, like this:

```
{
  "resource": {
    "SERVICE_API_URL":"http://my-service-svc.${env.KUBERNETES_HOST}:5000"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this will give the same result.